# typescriptでform要素を取得したい

Tags: typescript, dom

#### 実現したいこと

**value**の取得

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
プロパティ 'value' は型 'Element' に存在しません。
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```js
document.querySelector("#id").value
```

#### 試したこと

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

typescript:4.7.4
tsc:4.6.4
esnext

Comment: 「オブジェクトは 'null' である可能性があります。」というエラーについては理解しています。質問文にないのは意図的です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんにちは

英語版にありましたので、ここを参考してください：[リンク](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement)

> typescript は強いタイプなのでタイプを転換してください。

`プロパティ 'value' は型 'Element' に存在しません。`この言葉は既に分かりやすいと思いますが、`Element`タイプではvalueという属性はありません、つまりインスタンスの本当のタイプに明記しないといけないことです。

転記になりますが、答えは下記になります。

```
const a = document.querySelector("#id") as HTMLInputElement
console.log(a.value)
```